# Adding a number with 2 decimal places to a variable (2.50)

Tags: python, decimal

How do I add 2.50 to the cost?

Right now it just prints it out as 2.

```
cost = 0.00

r = open("toppings.txt")

bases = ["small","medium","large"]

toppings = ["Pepperoni","Chicken","Cajun Chicken","Mushrooms",
            "Red Onions","Sweetcorn","Ham","Cheese","Spicy Minced Beef",
            "Anchovies","Tuna","Peppers","Jalapenos","Green Chillies"] #0-13

def small():

    current = cost + 2.50

    print("Your current total cost is " + "£" + str(int(current)))
```

Comment: remove int(current) and use str(current) directly.

Comment: Well just remove the int()

Comment: `print("Your current total cost is £ %2f "% current)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- You loose the decimal places as soon as you convert it to an [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) in `int(current)`.
- If you always want two decimal places you have to use some sort of string formatting.

I would advise just to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with "2" decimal places (here enforced by the `.2f`):

```
'Your current total cost is £ {:.2f} '.format(current)
```

If you're working with "money"-like variables you should use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instead of floats, just so you don't need to take care of the "inexactness" of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting your float current bill amount to int in this line

```
print("Your current total cost is " + "£" + str(int(current)))
```

Instead use this command to print your current bill amount.

```
print("Your current total cost is " + "£" + "{0:.2f}".format(round(current,2)))
```

output

```
Your current total cost is £5.50
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` turns a number into a whole number. For example,`int(2.1) = 2`

Your last line should have just `str(current)`.

```
print("Your current total cost is " + "£" + str(current))
```